# Ninject Named Open Generic Type binding binds twice for a single bind call

Tags: vb.net, ninject

I am having issue with some Ninject binding code.

I am trying to bind an open generic type to a specific type based on binding name.

```
Sub Main
  dim k as new StandardKernel()
  k.Bind(GetType(SomeService(of))).To(gettype(SomeService(of A))).Named("A")
  k.Bind(GetType(SomeService(of))).To(gettype(SomeService(of B))).Named("B")
  k.Bind(GetType(SomeService(of))).To(gettype(SomeService(of C))).Named("C")

  k.Get(GetType(SomeService(of )), "B") ' Fails because the binding is defined more than once
  k.GetAll(GetType(SomeService(of )), "B") ' Returns two instances of SomeService(of B)

end sub

public class SomeService(of T)
end class

public class A
end class

public class B
end class

public class C
end class
```

The issue I have is that each binding gets mapped twice by ninject.

I have to use named bindings because when I will need to resolve the instances, I won't know the exact type.

What is wrong with my binding ? How can I achieve what I want ?

You can post answers using C# as I am fluent in both languages.

Comment: It might have to do with `SomeService` being an instanciatable type. have you tried binding `ISomeService` to `SomeService` instead? I would raise an issue @ ninject github. This is definitively interesting behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it. It appears that I was using an older version of Ninject which had an issue with the bindings of open generic types.

I was using version 3.0.1.10 and upgrading to 3.2.2.0 solved it.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/92